# Fitting copula using fitMvdc

Tags: r

I wanna fit copula to my data using fitMvdc, but I get an error. I believe it is syntax related to how I specify my start point for margins, however I was not able to find correct format.

For example the following code works fine:

```
normal <- normalCopula(param=rep(0.2, 3), dim=3 , dispstr="un")
myMvd<- mvdc(normal, c("exp","exp","exp"),
               param = list(list(rate=1), list(rate=1), list(rate=1)))
n<- 1000
x <- rMvdc(n, myMvd)
fit2 <- fitMvdc(x, myMvd, start = c(2,2,2,.2,.2,.2))
```

But when I change my margins to uniform or anything else, like below:

```
normal <- normalCopula(param=rep(0.2, 3), dim=3 , dispstr="un")
myMvd<- mvdc(normal, c("unif","unif","unif"),
           param = list(list(min=0,max=1), list(min=0,max=1), 
list(min=0,max=1)))
 n<- 1000
 x <- rMvdc(n, myMvd)
 fit2 <- fitMvdc(x, myMvd, start = c(0.1,1.1,0.1,1.1,0.1,1.1,.2,.2,.2))
```

I get following error:

```
non-finite finite-difference value [2]
```

and if I use method = "Nelder" as suggested by documentation error is:

```
possible convergence problem: optim gave code=1
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why do you need your margins to be uniform? in copula all margins will be uniform. So I think the problem is that.

Comment: This was an example, I needed margins to be uniform, exp, and gamma. Same error happens then.